# Colours Not Loading in Tailwind Theme Extension

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am attempting to make my first proper theme to aid in development and I've run into an issue, being that my custom colours won't actually load / display in my application unless they have been explicitly stated somewhere. As an example

```
// These two divs would load with their colours

<div className="bg-sky"/>
<div className="bg-primary"/>

// Though these two would not

<div className={`bg-${colourArgument1}`}/>
<div className={`bg-${colourArgument2} ${defaultlassName}`}/>
```

However, if colourArgument1 or colourArgument2 happened to be either 'sky' or 'primary' then they would infact load. This is what I mean by its like the colour must be explicitly stated before it will appear.

How I have set up the theme, which I realise is probably where I have gone wrong is:

```
//theme.js
    const theme = {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "#040830",
          100: "#091271",
          200: "#0C1897",
          300: "#0F1EBD",
          400: "#1224E2",
          500: "#2F3FEE",
          600: "#5562F1",
          700: "#7B85F4",
          800: "#A1A8F7",
          900: "#C7CBFA",
          1000: "#ECEEFD",
        },
      secondary: "#59C7CD",
      tertiary: "#266DD3",
      accent: "#B864A4",

      error: "#FF4A1C",

      white: "#FFFFFF",
      black: "#0A0A0A",

      lightContrast: "#b3b4c0",
      darkContrast: "#161717",

      "text-base": "white",
    },
  };

module.exports = { theme };
```

- 

```
// tailwind.config.js
const { theme } = require("./src/Theme/Theme.js");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    ...theme,
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
```

Then when I utilise tailwind classnames I just substitute out my custom colour names, as can be seen above in the examples at the start.

Any help would be appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did everything right except 1 thing. If you see your developer tool element tab for debugging you will realize that `<div className="bg-${colourArgument1}"/>` will give you a div having "bg-${colourArgument1}" as a classname which you dont want. What you want is the actual value of that variable.

I'm thinking that you might have missed it accidentally. Let me fix it for you. You can rewrite the same using template string like this.

So this

```
<div className="bg-${colourArgument1}"/>
<div className="bg-${colourArgument2}"/>
```

Will become

```
<div className=`bg-${colourArgument1}`/>
<div className=`bg-${colourArgument2}`/>
```

Note the backtick here instead of double quote.

Comment: Thank you for the response! However, I realised that I just lazily typed out the examples with double quotes opposed to backquotes as I have used in my code - that'll teach me for writing dummy code into SO... Sorry about that, I've edited the question